# Verificando checkbox

Tags: javascript, html5

Boa tarde.

Preciso de uma ajuda.
Estou criando um form em html5 para o trabalho da faculdade. Preciso verificar se ao menos 1 item do checkbox está marcado para que seja possível o envio dos dados.

Tentei usando if e não tive sucesso, o mesmo aconteceu com a tentativa de usar o for.

Estou usando o JS puro para validação.

```html
<div class="campo">
                <label>Áreas de interesse</label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="interesse" value="sim"> Análise
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="interesse" value="sim"> Banco de dados
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="interesse" value="sim"> Desenvolvimento
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="interesse" value="sim"> Redes de computadores
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="interesse" value="sim"> Engenharia de Software
                </label>
            </div>
```

Script que tentei:

for

Nesse caso só envia os dados se todas as opção forem marcadas.

```js
for (var i=0;i<interesse.length;i++) { 
                if (interesse[i].checked == true) { 
                    vInteresse = true;
                }  
                else {
                    alert("Escolha pelo menos uma área de interesse!");
                    event.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementsByName('interesse').focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

O if else, tentei com cada checkbox um nome diferente, fiz basicamente assim:

Nesse caso qualquer opção que eu marcasse daria a mensagem do else.

```js
if (analise==true || dba==true || dev==true || redes==true || engineer==true) {
  vInteresse = true;
} else {
  alert("Escolha pelo menos uma área de interesse!");
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementsByName('interesse').focus();
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Vale **[edit]** a pergunta para incluir o código JavaScript que você tentou fazer, bem como uma explicação mais detalhada sobre o que não deu certo.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Acho que agora ficou um pouco mais fácil de entender.

Answer (score 0):

pode tentar algo como:

```
      function validaCheckboxes() {
        const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='interesse'");
        let valid = false;
        checkboxes.forEach(check => {
          if (check.checked) {
            valid = true;
          }   
        }); 
        alert(valid ? 'Valido' : 'Invalid');
      }
```

Essa função vai procurar todos os inputs como `name="interesse"` e analisar se a propriedade `checked` deles esta true, e vai te dar um `alert` dizendo se algum a condição que voce descreveu esta valida ou não. Baseando-se nessa função so tratar o resultado como quiser :)

Comment: Jose, em partes funcionou. Muito obrigado.. Mas eu precisava que no lugar desse alert mostrando se foi válido ou inválido, eu teria que mostrar apenas um alert se caso nenhuma opção fosse marcada. Caso fosse true, apenas apareceria uma msg de dados enviados, que está em outro if, no final do script.

Comment: Voce pode mudar a função pra retornar `true` ou `false` e fazer toda validação na sua função de "submit" (acho que deve ser onde seu outro if fica), o alert foi para ilustrar o uso :)

Comment: Consegui aqui José, muito obrigado cara. Deixei tudo em uma mesma função validar.

Obrigado mesmo!!

Comment: Uma outra dúvida. Caso não esteja marcada nenhuma opção, como faço para o focus selecionar a primeira opção checkbox e radio ?

Comment: Vc pode usar o `document.querySelector("input[name='interesse']").focus()` querySelector seleciona some o primeiro que ele encontra